# How to copy a file inside a newly created folder and rename the file?

Tags: php, html

Good day experts!

I want to copy a file inside a newly created folder and rename the file but it seems there's something wrong with codes and I cant figure it out.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["newFileName"];
$folder = mkdir($name);
session_start();
$name = $_POST["newFileName2"];
$file = 'data.php';
$newfile = $_POST["newFileName"].'/'$_POST["newFileName2"].'.php';

file_exists($newfile) && die(" <center><br><br><br><br>The Exam name already exists.! Change it! <br><br> <a href='quiz.php'><button>GO BACK</button></a>");

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "Failed to create Quiz";
}else {
   echo "Created Successfully";
}
?>
```

Comment: $newfile = NAN.php or INF.php. It should be `$folder.'/'.$_POST["newFileName2"]`

Comment: `$folder = mkdir($name);` But `mkdir()` returns a boolean, thats `TRUE or FALSE`. So that line is one of your problems

Comment: This will a always die `file_exists($newfile) && die(" <center><br><br><br><br>The Exam name already exists.! Change it! <br><br> <a href='quiz.php'><button>GO BACK</button></a>");` You cannot test run a `die()` it kills the script `dead`

Comment: SO basically this is a **TYPO Nightmare**. Start again, but this time **first** open the [PHP Manual.](https://php.net)

Comment: Its also **V.v.Dangerous** creating php files that can then be run on your server from user input. Unless you intend to create a hackers party page

Comment: I did try the suggestion of robert also put the "file_exists.." after the "if(copy...)  but the errors goes like this now " PHP Warning:  copy(1/tle7.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\TNHS\copy.php on line 9,

Comment: Actually I manage to create a password protection on this page sir.

Comment: It's still a bit risky. Find a better way of deploying new code changes.

Comment: Based on this code, you might like to get that password protection checked!

Comment: Is `data.php` an existing file that you are trying to copy to the newly created folder?

Comment: @riggsfolly Yes sir, it exists.

Comment: I GOT IT ALREADY!!!!! WEEEEEEEEW. Little bit tricky this one. mkdir($name, 0777) and $newfile = $_POST["newFileName"].'/'.$name2.'.php'; is the solution. woah. I appreciate for the help sirs/maam!! What i need is to revisit php manual. THnx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if ( !isset($_POST["newFileName"], $_POST["newFileName2"]) ) {
    echo "An meaningful error message";
    exit;
}
$existingFile = 'data.php';

// $_POST["newFileName"] is the new folder name
// may have been better named $_POST["newFolder"] :)
$folder = '';
$folder = $_POST["newFileName"];
if ( ! mkdir($folder) ) {
    echo 'Cannot create a folder with that name';
    exit;
}

$newFilename = $_POST["newFileName2"];
$newfile = "$folder/$_POST[newFileName2].php";

if ( file_exists($newfile) ) {
    echo " <center><br><br><br><br>The Exam name already exists.! Change it! <br><br> <a href='quiz.php'><button>GO BACK</button></a>";
    exit;
}  

if (!copy($existingFile, $newfile)) {
    echo "Failed to create Quiz";
}else {
   echo "Created Successfully";
}
```